# How to reduce a matrix with saving a the maximum element value?

Tags: java, algorithm

Suppose I have a matrix

```
int[][] matrix = {
        // 0     1     2
        {0,0,  0,0,  0,0}, // 0
        {0,1,  0,0,  0,0},

        {1,1,  0,0,  0,0}, // 1
        {0,0,  0,0,  0,1} 
};

int newCellSize = 2;
```

I want to reduce it with keeping a max value of a cell. For example,

`matrix` =>

```
int[][] reducedMatrix = {
        {1, 0, 0},
        {1, 0, 1}
};
```

How can I do that? How to iterate through `matrix` elements and map them to `reducedMatrix` cells?

Here is my try:

```
private static int[][] reduceMatrix(int[][] matrix, int cellSize) {

    int a = (int)ceil((double)matrix.length/cellSize);
    int b = (int)ceil((double)matrix[0].length/cellSize);

    int[][] reduced = new int[a][b];

    for(int i=0; i < matrix.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j < matrix[i].length; j++){

            int n= i / cellSize;
            int m= j / cellSize;

            int elem = matrix[i][j];

            if(elem > 0){
                reduced[n > 0 ? n : 0][m > 0 ? m : 0]=elem;
            }
        }
    }

    return reduced;
}
```

Comment: show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: So far I don't know from what point should I start to develop an algorithm.

Comment: This is a 4*6 matrix that you have reduced to 2*3. How exactly do you define a cell here?

Comment: Does cell mean every 2*2 block? And, if that is the case, is the initial matrix always an even*even matrix?

Comment: So, is the initial matrix always an even*even matrix?

Comment: No, it could be any x*x size actually.

Comment: For an odd * even, even * odd or odd * odd matrix, how do you define a cell then?

Comment: Sorry, a cell has x*x size.

Comment: So, the cell size can be x * x and matrix size is a * b. Is it safe to assume that a%x=0 and b%x=0?

Comment: Yes, it's safe.

Answer (score 0):

This little piece of code should do the trick:

```
int[][] reduceMatrix(int[][] matrix, int cellSize, int rows, int cols) {
    int [][] reducedMatrix = new int[rows/cellSize][cols/cellSize];
    for (int i=0; i<rows; i+=cellSize) {
        for (int j=0; j<cols; j+=cellSize) {
            int max=-INF;
            for (k=i;k<cellSize;k++)
                for (l=j;l<cellSize;l++)
                    if (matrix[k][l]>max)
                        max=matrix[k][l];
            reducedMatrix[i/cellSize][j/cellSize] = max;
        }
    }
    return reducedMatrix;
}
```